# Co-ordinates for last drawn graph using functional plot

Tags: d3.js

Using [d3 functional plot](https://github.com/mauriciopoppe/function-plot/)(derivatives, polar, parametric expressions) is there any way to get the last drawn graph co-ordinates.

The reason I need those co-ordinates is to zoom(highlight) the recently drawn graph.

And Also please let me know if there is any way to show the co-ordinates(x, y) for polar and parametric expression on the graph using [functional plot](https://github.com/mauriciopoppe/function-plot/) library as it's showing for derivative expressions.